# Lazy fetch with OneToOne and OneToMany not working

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have 3 entities Person, Employee, PeopleEmail:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person
{
private String id;
private String lastName;
private String middleName;
private String firstName;
private Employee employee;
private Set<PeopleEmail> peopleEmail;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@LazyToOne(value = LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
})
public Set<PeopleEmail> getPeopleEmail() {
    return peopleEmail;
}

public void setPeopleEmail(Set<PeopleEmail> peopleEmail) {
    this.peopleEmail = peopleEmail;
}

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
@LazyToOne(value = LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}

public void setEmployee (Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}
...
}
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
  private String employeeId;
  private String spouseFirst;
  private String spouseLast;
  private String supervisorName;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID", nullable = false, length = 10)
  public String getEmployeeId() {
   return employeeId;
  }

  public void setEmployeeId(String employeeId) {
   this.employeeId = employeeId;
  }
  ....
}
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PEOPLE_EMAIL")
public class PeopleEmail
{
private String personEmailTypes;
private String personEmailAddresses;
private String personPreferredEmail;
private PeopleEmailPK peopleEmailPK;
private Long pos;

@EmbeddedId
public PeopleEmailPK getId()
{
    return peopleEmailPK;
}

public void setId(PeopleEmailPK peopleEmailPK)
{
    this.peopleEmailPK = peopleEmailPK;
}
```

The database that I am working with can't be altered and is very unnormalized.  Hence the PeopleEmailPK primary key (if you need to see this class I would be glad to provide it)

I also have this added to my pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                        <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
                        <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                        <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>
                        <enableExtendedEnhancement>false</enableExtendedEnhancement>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The problem is no matter what I do, I cannot get Employee and PeopleEmail to load lazily.  When I call anything related to Person it runs 3 queries.

For what its worth I am using Hibernate 5.0.12 in a Spring Boot project

Comment: What are the 3 queries doing?  What tables are they querying from?

Comment: Have you tried with LazyToOneOption.PROXY?

Comment: @Dan the 3 queries are basically just select <all objects in the entity> from person/employee/peopleEmail where id = ? (an id passed through my API)

Comment: @Priyesh LazyToOneOption.PROXY option is not working either

Comment: @Dan: were you able to figure out the issue?